# How to have Java method return generic list of any type?

Tags: java, list, generics, reflection, casting

I would like to write a method that would return a `java.util.List` of any type **without the need to typecast anything**:

```
List<User> users = magicalListGetter(User.class);

List<Vehicle> vehicles = magicalListGetter(Vehicle.class);

List<String> strings = magicalListGetter(String.class);
```

What would the method signature look like? Something like this, perhaps(?):

```
public List<<?> ?> magicalListGetter(Class<?> clazz) {
    List<?> list = doMagicalVooDooHere();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the list to be populated via reflection? Otherwise just use `new ArrayList<>()`.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
private Object actuallyT;

public <T> List<T> magicalListGetter(Class<T> klazz) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(klazz.cast(actuallyT));
    try {
        list.add(klazz.getConstructor().newInstance()); // If default constructor
    } ...
    return list;
}
```

One can give a generic type parameter to a method too. You have correctly deduced that one needs the correct class instance, to create things (`klazz.getConstructor().newInstance()`).

Answer (score 28):

No need to even pass the class:

```
public <T> List<T> magicalListGetter() {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Comment: I think that you need to pass a class when you want to add items.

Comment: This is the best solution if you want to manipulate the list and simply return the same type. (For instance, reversing the order, reducing the number of items, etc.) Passing a class would only be needed if you need to instantiate a new object of type T.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is doing the following:

```
public class UserList extends List<User>{

}

public <T> T magicalListGetter(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<?> list = doMagicalVooDooHere();
    return (T)list;
}

List<User> users = magicalListGetter(UserList.class);
```

`

Answer (score 4):

Let us have `List<Object> objectList` which we want to cast to `List<T>`

```
public <T> List<T> list(Class<T> c, List<Object> objectList){        
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();       
    for (Object o : objectList){
        T t = c.cast(o);
        list.add(t);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the old way:

```
public List magicalListGetter() {
    List list = doMagicalVooDooHere();

    return list;
}
```

or you can use `Object` and the parent class of everything:

```
public List<Object> magicalListGetter() {
    List<Object> list = doMagicalVooDooHere();

    return list;
}
```

*Note* Perhaps there is a better parent class for all the objects you will put in the list. For example, `Number` would allow you to put `Double` and `Integer` in there.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
publiс <T> List<T> magicalListGetter(Class<T> clazz) {
    List list = doMagicalVooDooHere();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: why pass `clazz` if you're not gonna use it?

Comment: it was like this in the question, probably OP is going to use it somehow

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast to List and then check if every element can be casted to T.

```
public <T> List<T> asList(final Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> values = (List<T>) this.value;
    values.forEach(clazz::cast);
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given some legacy code that returns an untyped `List`

```
List list = database.GetCustomers(); //legacy code returns untyped list
```

we will use a helper function:

```
public static <T> @NotNull List<T> castList(final @NotNull Iterable sourceList)
{
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object o : sourceList)
        result.add((T)o);

    return result;
}
```

to convert the returned list to a generic typed `List<T>`:

```
List<Customer> = castList(database.GetCustomers()); //cast the list the appropriate type
```

Why Java doesn't have extension methods is quite beyond me.

Comment: The raw type is a subtype. A simple `List<Customer> customers = (List<Customer>) list;` will suffice.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you can completely delete the   <stuff>   , which will generate a warning and you can use an, @ suppress warnings. If you really want it to be generic, but to use any of its elements you will have to do type casting. For instance, I made a simple bubble sort function and it uses a generic type when sorting the list, which is actually an array of Comparable in this case. If you wish to use an item, do something like: System.out.println((Double)arrayOfDoubles[0] + (Double)arrayOfDoubles[1]); because I stuffed Double(s) into Comparable(s) which is polymorphism since all Double(s) inherit from Comparable to allow easy sorting through Collections.sort()

```
        //INDENT TO DISPLAY CODE ON STACK-OVERFLOW
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void simpleBubbleSort_ascending(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Comparable[] arrayOfDoubles)
{
//VARS
    //looping
    int end      =      arrayOfDoubles.length - 1;//the last index in our loops
    int iterationsMax = arrayOfDoubles.length - 1;

    //swapping
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Comparable tempSwap = 0.0;//a temporary double used in the swap process
    int elementP1 = 1;//element + 1,   an index for comparing and swapping


//CODE
    //do up to 'iterationsMax' many iterations
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterationsMax; iteration++)
    {
        //go through each element and compare it to the next element
        for (int element = 0; element < end; element++)
        {
            elementP1 = element + 1;

            //if the elements need to be swapped, swap them
            if (arrayOfDoubles[element].compareTo(arrayOfDoubles[elementP1])==1)
            {
                //swap
                tempSwap = arrayOfDoubles[element];
                arrayOfDoubles[element] = arrayOfDoubles[elementP1];
                arrayOfDoubles[elementP1] = tempSwap;
            }
        }
    }
}//END public static void simpleBubbleSort_ascending(double[] arrayOfDoubles)
```