# How to create method that will return List of any class that extends one superclass

Tags: java, generics

I am developing a small web app in Spring.

I would like to avoid repeating code and thus I would like to create one method in service layer that will call appropriate DAO's method based on arguments.

For one abstract payment class i have three subclasses (energy, water, gas).
Also I have enum class called `Media`.

In the service I wanted to create something like this: 
(based on [How to have Java method return generic list of any type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840483/how-to-have-java-method-return-generic-list-of-any-type))

```
@Autowired
ReadingDao<ReadingEnergy, InvoiceEnergy> energy;
@Autowired
ReadingWaterDAO water;
@Autowired
ReadingDao<ReadingGas, InvoiceGas> gas;

 @Override
public <T extends ReadingAbstract> List<T> getReadingsForTenant(Apartment apartment, Media media) {
    ReadingAbstract gg = new ReadingEnergy();

switch (media) {
    case ENERGY:
        return energy.getListForTenant(apartment);
        break;
    case GAS:

        return gas.getListForTenant(apartment);
        break;
    case WATER:

        return water.getListForTenant(apartment);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Unfortunately I get

```
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<ReadingEnergy> to List<T>
```

I have also tried with this:

```
public  List<?> getReadingsForTenant(Apartment apartment, Media media) {

        switch (media) {
        case ENERGY:
            System.out.println("getReadingsForTenant - energia");
            return energy.getListForTenant(apartment);

        case GAS:
            System.out.println("getReadingsForTenant - gas");
            return gas.getListForTenant(apartment);

        case WATER:
            System.out.println("getReadingsForTenant - woda");
            return water.getListForTenant(apartment);

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

}
```

This generally works BUT when I create a new object

```
Apartment ap = (some apartment);
List<ReadingWater> list = (List<ReadingWater>) readingService.getReadingsForTenant(ap, Media.WATER);
```

I get:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<capture#3-of ?> to List<ReadingWater>
```

I could use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` but that doesn't look to good for me.

**What is the proper way to handle such stuff?**

Comment: Note: the `break` after a `return` statement is unreachable, and so is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a return type which depends upon a runtime argument: types have to be known at compile time.

The only return type of this method which can be matched for all of your return statements is: `List<? extends ReadingAbstract>`. It could *maybe* be `List<ReadingAbstract>`, but only if your DAOs return that type.

If you want to know the specific element type of the list, you need a separate method for each media type:

```
public List<ReadingWater> getWaterReadingsForTenant(Apartment apartment);
public List<ReadingGas> getGasReadingsForTenant(Apartment apartment);
// etc.
```

which works for your example use case, since you are statically specifying `Media.WATER`: just statically call `getWaterReadingsForTenant` instead.

---

> I could use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") but that doesn't look to good for me.

Compiler warnings are there for a reason. You could equally have written this:

```
List<ReadingWater> list =
    (List<ReadingWater>) readingService.getReadingsForTenant(ap, Media.GAS);
```

and that would cause a runtime failure - just not at this line. So then you'd have a hog of a time tracking down why you're getting `ClassCastException`s in far distant code.