# Java generic function to get JSON

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

I wanted to parse Objects from `JSON` and It works fine, but I wanted to generalize my function, to get every type I want. I tried to use generic type, but It gave me error.

My code:

```
//It works, but It's not universal
Type type = new TypeToken<List<WeatherParameter>>(){}.getType();
List<WeatherParameter> contactList = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);

//My function:
public static <T> List<T> getArrayFromJSON(String json) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
    }

Usage:
List<WeatherParameter> contactList = getArrayFromJSON(json);

//Error:
com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.entity.model.WeatherParameter.
```

Why generic type `T` doesn't work in a `TypeToken<List<T>>`?

**UPDATE**

I've changed my function:

```
public static <T> List<T> getArrayFromJSON(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        List<Object> objectList = GSON.fromJson(json, type);
        for(Object o : objectList){
            list.add(clazz.cast(o));
        }
        return list;
    }
```

And it crashes on line `list.add(clazz.cast(o));`, error is the same: `ClassCastException`.

**Full stack trace:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap to com.entity.model.WeatherParameter
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3361)
    at com.server.utils.JsonUtils.getArrayFromJSON(JsonUtils.java:23)
    at com.server.task.ShowDataTask.process(ShowDataTask.java:21)
    at com.server.task.AbstractTask.run(AbstractTask.java:16)
    at com.server.utils.TaskUtils.lambda$doGet$1(TaskUtils.java:17)
    at com.server.utils.TaskUtils$$Lambda$22/18975860.handle(Unknown Source)
    at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:61)
    at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:128)
    at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As I said, 23 line in JsonUtils: `list.add(clazz.cast(o));`
I call it this way:

```
List<WeatherParameter> weatherParameterList = JsonUtils.getArrayFromJSON(json, WeatherParameter.class);
```

Comment: Is this a compile-time or run-time error? On which line is it reported? Is this the whole error message or truncated?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou It occurs when I want to use item from list, like: `System.out.println(contactList.get(0).getId());`

Comment: Can you provide a full stack trace?

Answer (score 4):

The basic reason why your generic method is failing compilation is that after type erasure, the `getArrayFromJSON()` method returns a `List<Object>`, not a `List<WeatherParameter>`.  Suppose that the compiler allowed your code to pass.  Then it would be possible for you to assign a list of objects to list of weather parameters.  But not every object is a weather parameter, so this might fail in a class cast exception.

One way to get around this would be to pass type information for the `WeatherParameter` class to your custom method, i.e.

```
public static <T> List<T> getArrayFromJSON(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    // use class information somehow...
}
```

You might have a hard time since the class information would probably be needed inside the GSON library.

Have a look at the following question to get thinking about this:

[How to have Java method return generic list of any type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840483/how-to-have-java-method-return-generic-list-of-any-type)

Comment: This code doesn't look far off.  Maybe you could update your question with this second attempt.

Comment: @KurdTt- what you need is to use clazz on this line: `Type type = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();` instead of using T (which is erased at runtime).