# Generic type as method argument

Tags: java, generics

I would like to create a method which can accept an object type as a parameter, which I can then use to instantiate another object.

For example, pass in type `String` to the method, and within the method body, do

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
String s = new String("abc");
```

How do I go about doing this?

Edit:

[How to have Java method return generic list of any type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840483/how-to-have-java-method-return-generic-list-of-any-type) does answer the first part of my question.

As a followup, could I create an instance of the passed in type within the method body as in the second line in the code snippet above?

Comment: There are many tutorials about generics in Java ... have you tried at least one of them?

Comment: I've read up on a few tutorials which have helped me implement code that utilizes generics. Unfortunately, I can't figure this particular problem out. A link, if possible, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, one of the first things you must have learned if you learned generics was that you can't call `new` with a generic type because generic types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: @RealSkeptic This wouldn't be necessary here anyway and that wouldn't be an issue for the used ArrayList.

Comment: @Tom to create an array list you'll have to use a *raw* one, and cast it to the appropriate type and ignore the warnings.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Nonsense. *You* know the passed type at compile-time and can you that for your list.

Comment: @Tom When you are working with generic classes there are some cases when you are don't know about the class you need to instantiate.

Comment: @RealSkeptic http://ideone.com/MDn1vM isn't that what op is asking for?

Comment: @matt No, I think not. The parameter passed to that method is an object, not a type, and the reason it works is that the method is a generic method, which requires knowing the type at runtime, not passing it as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any mechanism in order to get that just with generics. You have to use reflection to get that.

```
public <T> T instantiator(Class<T> c){
    if (c != null){
        try {
            return (T) c.getConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

However the reflections may fail if it is not used carefully. This method I just wrote works fine if the class has a constructor with no parameters. For example, `instantiator(String.class);` and `instantiator(Exception.class);` would work properly since the have an empty constructor but `instantiator(Integer.class)` won't run.

Comment: The SO question that @Tom linked to above answered the first part of my question, this answers the second part.