# receiving a webElement List - casting error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a method like this

```
  public List<WebElement> AgreeAllow(){

          WebElement ButtonAgree = (WebElement) driver.findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator(SelectorRepo.AgreeButton);
          WebElement ButtonAllow = (WebElement) driver.findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator(SelectorRepo.AllowButton);

          List<WebElement> AgreeAllowFunction = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

         // ArrayList AgreeAllowFunction = new ArrayList<WebElement>(); 
          AgreeAllowFunction.add(ButtonAgree);
          AgreeAllowFunction.add(ButtonAllow);

          return AgreeAllowFunction;

      }
```

and I am calling `AgreeAllow()` like this in a different file

```
List<WebElement>  AgreeAllowHandler =  PageObjectOneInst.AgreeAllow();


      tAction.tap((WebElement) AgreeAllowHandler.get(0));
      tAction.tap((WebElement) AgreeAllowHandler.get(1));
      ...
      ...
```

Its giving me this error
`java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement`

I tried this also, but couldn't resolve

```
 List<WebElement>  AgreeAllowHandler =   List<WebElement>  PageObjectOneInst.AgreeAllow();
```

I have looked at several SO questions. I tried below also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840483/how-to-have-java-method-return-generic-list-of-any-type)

```
List<WebElement>  AgreeAllowHandler = new ArrayList<>();      
      for (WebElement wElement : PageObjectOneInst.AgreeAllow()){
          Class <WebElement> c = null;
          WebElement we =  c.cast(wElement);
          AgreeAllowHandler.add(we);
        }
```

how do I receive/cast it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator` returns list of elements. Use `findElementByAndroidUIAutomator` instead.

```
 public List<WebElement> AgreeAllow(){

      WebElement ButtonAgree = (WebElement) driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(SelectorRepo.AgreeButton);
      WebElement ButtonAllow = (WebElement) driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(SelectorRepo.AllowButton);
      ...
 }
```

https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/FindsByAndroidUIAutomator.html