# Java - Return set of all objects of certain type T where T is passed to the method

Tags: java, generics, types, set

I'm looking to write a method that given an original set A and a type T returns a new set containing all the objects of type T in A.

I've set up a test with a `Person` class and its subclasses `Man` and `Woman`, along with a `World` class to house the set of `Person` objects.

```
public class World {

    public World() {
        this.people = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        getAllPeople().add(person);
    }

    public void removePerson(Person person) {
        getAllPeople().remove(person);
    }

    public Set<Person> getAllPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public <T> Set<T> getAllPeople(Class<T> cls) {
        Set<T> ItemsOfClass = new HashSet<>();
        // Incompatible type error on next line
        ItemsOfClass = getAllPeople().stream().filter(object -> object.getClass().equals(cls)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return ItemsOfClass;
    }

    public Set<Person> people;
}
```

So I'd like `getAllPeople(Man.class)` to return a new set of `Man` objects.

My current implementation of `getAllPeople` is based on the following answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17840541 and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16727596
although I can't figure out how they are supposed to fit together, if at all.

I'm not good at generics so any and all explanation/advice is welcome.

Comment: Note that `T` is like the very worst variable name you can choose. Does that even compile?

Comment: Add a `map(T::cast)` to your stream, after the `filter`.

Comment: @luk2302 it would. It's just like [`String String = "";`](https://ideone.com/dTvBxN): vile, confusing, but valid.

Comment: @AndyTurner Criticism is valid, duly noted. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Stream<Person>` that you are trying to collect into a `Set<T>`. But a `Stream<Person>` will produce a `Set<Person>`.

You can map your `Person` instances to `T` instances and get a `Stream<T>`.

```
public <T> Set<T> getAllPeople(Class<T> cls) {
    Set<T> itemsOfClass = getAllPeople().stream()
              .filter(cls::isInstance)
              .map(cls::cast)
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return itemsOfClass;
}
```

This uses `cls::isInstance` as a predicate to find elements of the class `cls`, and `cls::cast` as a mapper to regard your elements as `T` instances instead of `Person` instances.

Comment: Note that `Class.isInstance()` is not a equivalent of  `getClass().equals(..)` as it determines whether the parameter can be assigned to a variable with the type of the class. So, it will return `true` also for subclasses.

Comment: @davidxxx I took a guess that that was what the OP wanted and just didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your element inside stream first:

```
public <T> Set<T> getAllPeople(Class<T> clazz) {
    return obj.stream().filter(object -> object.getClass().equals(clazz))
              .map(v -> (T) v).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is very probably the assignment :

```
 ItemsOfClass = getAllPeople().stream().filter(object -> object.getClass().equals(T)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The created `Set` by the `collect()` method is not typed as `Set<T>` even if you filtered only object which the class is `T`.
Actually you iterate on `Person`. So you collect a `Set<Person>`
So you are constraint to cast explicitly `Set<Person>` to `Set<T>` such as :

```
 ItemsOfClass = (Set<T>) getAllPeople().stream()
                                       .filter(object -> object.getClass().equals(T))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or with `Class::cast` such as :

```
 ItemsOfClass =  getAllPeople().stream()
                              .filter(object -> object.getClass().equals(T))
                              .map(T::cast)
                              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```