# how to implement the method which have parameter same but different signature

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, design-patterns, collections

I have to implement the function which have the same functionality but different return type and the parameter of the function is also same.

```
public static List<Base> remove(List<Subclass> arrange ) {
    List<Base>update = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Subclass arranging : arrange){
        //For-loop body here
    }
    return update;
}

public static List<Subclass> remove(List<Subclass> arrange ) {
    List<Subclass>update = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Subclass arranging : arrange){
        //For-loop body here
    }
    return update;
}
```

Here `Base` and `Subclass` are the classes already defined.

Only one method should be there named `remove` because the functionality is same so redundancy will occur if I implement the same method twice just because of different datatype

Comment: You could use one method with generics in case the only difference is the return type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have Java method return generic list of any type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840483/how-to-have-java-method-return-generic-list-of-any-type)

Comment: It is not possible to do it if they have the same name. How would the compiler be able to know which one to execute when you are calling remove(List)? The one which is returning List<Base> or List<Subclass>?

Comment: Java does not support return-type-based method overloading. Rename the method and call one from another, if you want to avoid redundancy. [link](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983207)

Comment: You can create a common method call remove(List<T> arrange) and call it from both the classes.

Comment: Just keep `List<Subclass> remove(List<Subclass>)` and drop the other. There is no reason for keeping a second method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a method which has the same logic with different parameter types you can create a generic version of such method. In your case such a method would look like:

```
    public static <T> List<T> remove(List<T> arrange) {
        List<T> update = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (T arranging : arrange) {
            //For-loop body here
        }
        return update;
    }
```

Then you can use this method with any `T` (`Base` or `Subclass`) and the method will work with the elements of the list pass as argument and return the appropriate type as well:

```
        List<Subclass> one = ...;
        one = remove(one);
        
        List<Base> two = ...;
        two = remove(two);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is called generic method.

A single generic method declaration that can be called with arguments of different types. The generic function you need will look like this:

```
public static < E > List<E> remove( List<E> arrange ) {...}
```

In the case that there are more than one generic type and one is the subclass of the other (e.g. BaseClass and SubClass), the declaration will look like

```
public static < E, F > List<E> remove( List<F extends E> arrange ) {...}
```

For more information, you can refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm

Answer (score 0):

I see you are in a situation where two methods does almost the same thing but present the result differently to the caller. Use generics if the domain of return type is larger.
`public static E remove(List<E> arrange)`

If the return types are limited you might develop a relationship between Base and SubClass. And use co-variances to deal with multiple return types.